# Create a New Folder using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, office365api

I am trying to create a new folder under the `root` of my `onedrive` by making a call to the following end point :

**Request:**

```
POST graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/rootId/children
Content-Type: application/json
{
 "name": "New Folder",
 "folder": { },
 "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
}
```

**Expected Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type: application/json
{
 "createdBy": {
  "user": {
    ...
```

**Obtained Response:**

```
200 OK
```

When I make a call to this endpoint using Postman, I get a list of children under the root folder and the folder is not created.
Is the any way to resolve this?
Is there anything that i am doing wrong?
Kindly let me know.

Comment: How are you obtaining `rootId`? Have you tried using `/me/drive/root/children`?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur i've even tried using this. But, even that didn't work for me. To obtain `rootId`, i'm making a GET request to the end point `/me/drive/root`. The returned response contains details about the root along with it's `rootId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use HTTPS request for all Microsoft Graph APIs

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/<rootId>/children
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a link to the docs page with that endpoint?

You can try make request to `drive/root/children`

below is a c# code for that:

```
var folder = new DriveItem { Name = "New Folder", Folder = new Folder() };
            await client.Drive.Root.Children.Request().AddAsync(folder);
```

I used it a bit differently for something else, but should work analogically for you.

As other workaround, you can try to get the id of your drive id and drive root item id and then try to use the the endpoint without "`me/`" and "`drives/{driveId}/items/{rootItemId}`" instead.

PS. Have you inspected your oneDrive to obesrve the results of your calls? What do they produce?

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for the delay.
Here is a link to the docs page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#example